# 8086 d bit in opcode 1: what is the more common value, 0 or 1?

Tags: x86, dos, machine-code, x86-emulation

For quite a lot of 8086 instructions, bit 1 of opcode 1 is a direction bit d (not to be confused with the DF flag), allowing two ways to encode the same instruction.

An emulator I am writing can decode 'from' and 'to' for either d=0 or d=1 but not both, due to space constraints. The undecoded value of d is handled by swapping 'from' and 'to', making it slower.

Does DOS in particular use d=0 in preference to d=1, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Only reg-reg instructions have a choice; then it probably depends on the assembler.  (So beware of sample bias if you only profile a few executables with your emulator to get counts.)

I'd guess modern compiler-generated code will more often use memory-source operands like `add reg, [esp+12]` or something, but for 16-bit hand-written it could really go either way.  Beginner code seen on Stack Overflow shows a large tendency to use craptastic static storage ("named variables") instead of registers.

As for DOS *itself*, I'd really recommend just profiling some typical uses with your emulator to find out what those binaries really do.

**Add a counter to your emulator to record how many times you took the "fast" vs. "slow" ways**.  If it turns out you took the slow way a lot more, rewrite the code to make that the fast path.